# Application installation failed in android studio?

Tags: android, android-runtime

when i run the app in mobile, "Application installation failed" dialog came.

Installation failed since the device possibly has stale dexed jars that don't match the current version (dexopt error).
In order to proceed, you have to uninstall the existing application.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

dialog is displaying. Please anyone help me out.

Comment: Uninstall the app on phone and then try to run again!

Comment: i uninstall the application so many times. And for any application also it is showing same thing

Comment: try clean or rebuild your project. Check jar dependencies as well.

Comment: could please tell me how to check jar dependencies!

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37207831/2826147

Answer (score 0):

My solution is as follows: set the option in Android Studio in Instant Run is not selected
(1) find the options in Instant Run based on the following path
File - Settings - Build, Execution, Deployment - Instant Run
(2) Enable Run to swap changes on deploy (default enabled) in the selection box to cancel the Instant code/resource.