# no changes to deploy android studio 2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.1, android-instant-run, instant-run

**Android Studio 2.1 instant run is not updating the app on the device**

I observed an issue with AndroidStudio 2.1. When I run the app with small java code changes, it doesn't update app on the device sometimes. Instead it shows a message

> No changes to deploy // (Don't show again)

Am I missing any thing here?
As a work around I do clean build every time in order to reflect the changes in app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623917/first-launch-take-long-time-in-android-studio-2-0-gradle-2-0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Upgrade Android studio version to 3** or more. this bug is resolved.

This was a bug on version 2.0 instant run and **issues were reported** check these links

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199884  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195062
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206698
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=209413
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206627

thing to do would be to disable Instant Run entirely by

> Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run > Enable
>   Instant Run

You can file a bug at this link: [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192708&template=840533)

please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35169716/2826147 to turn it off.

Comment: is this bug repaired in newer versions of android studio (3.* etc.)??

Comment: I am using A.S. 3.0.1 and issue still persist

Comment: @an_droid_dev try resinstalling android studio

Comment: @AmitVaghela thx for reply. In my case should was a gradle issue, i solved it deleting Gradle's cache.

Answer (score 1):

Thats a bug in Android Studio, I noticed it in build `2.0` sometimes it failed to update, so what i do is I rebuild the entire project, one more thing, if you have `multidex` enabled and your device is not running `5 <`it will not work, make sure its disabled and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

I have just noticed that whenever i closed my app and then run it worked. See my post here. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37357665/5923606