# instant run not working: forcing kill and restart app

Tags: android, android-studio

instant run worked for me and I don't know why it stopped:
I see the thunderbolt icon of the instance run but when I click it,  a popup appears :

"Restart App?
The app is already running. Would you like to kill it and restart the session?"
the available options are "restart app"\ "cancel"

when restart popup is shown :
"Instant Run is disabled: variant 'debug' uses an unsupported feature (e.g. ProGuard)"

(I've tried to comment progourd in gradle- didn't help)

what am I missing?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37207831/2826147) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37207831/2826147) SO answer