# Instant Run seem to be randomly not working

Tags: android, android-studio, instant-run

I have Android Studio 2.1.2, with Instant Run enabled.

Almost the time, Instant Run works and updates my application when I hit Run (or Shift+F10). But sometime, randomly, **Instant Run does not work** (I'm still running the application, and see the Run button with "lightning icon"), then I have to

> Run > Clean and Rerun (Ctrl + F5)

to make it update my application (I see the changes in UI, logs...).

After that, it works then randomly not. 
**I have tried with Android Studio 2.0, 2.1.2 and even the 2.2**, always see this issue. I don't know what I did wrong, and how to fix this issue?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37207831/2826147) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35169716/2826147) answer