# Disable Instant Run Android Studio 2.2 Preview 5

Tags: android, android-studio

I am Unable to disable my Instant Run , and i want to disable it because i am facing different kind of problems with Libraries like `SugarORM` , Here is what i am doing.

> File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings

There is No `Instant Run` Option There !!!

[image: Settings1]

[image: Setting2]

Where is `instant run` , and how can i disable it in MAC/windows

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37207831/2826147) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35169716/2826147)

Comment: @AmitVaghela so what you are saying that instant run is not available in current version , or it is not visible because of some kind of bug ?

Comment: what is your gradle plugin version?

Comment: Seems to be a bug that is not visible, did you try via shift + Command + A Find Action and search for "enable instant run"?

Comment: yep i did not working

Comment: use this link : > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168753/instant-run-in-android-studio-2-0-how-to-turn-off

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exact isuue with SugarORM lib.

here what I did : (I'll give you two ways to achive that one disable for specefic project, and second for whole android studio):

1. **if you want to disable instant-run ONLY for the project that is not compatible** (i.e the one with SugarORM lib)

on root of your projct open gradle-->gradle-wrapper.properties then change the value
 `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip`

and
 on your project build.gradle change the value

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
```

### [image]

2. **If you want to disable instant-run for all project (Across Android Studio)**

in older version of AS settings for instant run is

```
File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings ->Build, Execution,Deployment
```

In most recent version of AS, instant run settings is in Preference
[image]

[image]