# How to configure instant run to consider any changes

Tags: android-studio

Is it possible to configure instant run to consider changes in layout files, commenting and uncommenting lines, annotations which changes auto generated code?
If any of above are changed instant run still considers, that code was not changed.

Comment: please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37207831/2826147)

Comment: @AmitVaghela it considers to disable it at all, i want to keep it on

Comment: than check that box in http://stackoverflow.com/a/35169716/2826147 answer

Comment: can you elaborate ?

Comment: @AmitVaghela if you mean to check if checkboxes are checked - they are.