# Android Studio 2.2: transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug task fails for older devices

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2, android-instant-run

I have a class marked with `@TargetApi(21)` attribute and that uses, well, API Level 21 classes. I don't invoke the class if the app is running on an older device. However, with Instant Run enabled, I cannot debug my app on say an API Level 18 device, because then the task `app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug` fails. Running and debugging the app on API Level 21+ devices is no problem. What would be the solution? How to explain to Android Studio to ignore that file? I guess I've already did that with `@TargetApi` attribute...

Comment: there are some bugs in instant run function please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/37207831/2826147.

Comment: @AmitVaghela If I don't get an answer (maybe I'm overlooking something), I'll of course file a bug.

Comment: okay, sir. i thought that it might help you.