# Execution failed for task ':app:countPlayUatDexMethods'

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, android-instant-run

I'm facing the following error while building the app in Android Studio 3.1.3 with Instant Run enabled.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:countPlayUatDexMethods'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Rakesh\Desktop\appWorkspace\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-resources\resources-play\UAT-PLAY.apk (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Log says :

```
:app:countPlayUatDexMethods FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:countPlayUatDexMethods'.
    > java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Rakesh\Desktop\appWorkspace\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-resources\resources-play\UAT-PLAY.apk (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Versions details :

- Android Studio : 3.1.3
- Android gradle plugin : 3.1.3
- gradle wrapper : 4.4
- Kotlin plugin : 1.2.30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause and it's solution. [`dexcount-gradle-plugin`](https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin) was the trouble maker. I updated its version to :

```
classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.8.3'
```

Thanks to the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47370033/6813468) link.